# How to make n() do not count NAs too in tidyverse?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, na

Consider the MWE below, where we have `Amt` indicating different amounts (from 1 to 40 with NAs) for each `Food` item and another variable indicating the `Site` of that food item. I wanted a summary median and a count `n()` of food items but for those without `NA`.

**MWE**

```
 mwe <- data.frame(
  Site = sample(rep(c("Home", "Office"), size = 884)),
  Food = sample(rep(c("Banana","Apple","Egg","Berry","Tomato","Potato","Bean","Pea","Nuts","Onion","Carrot","Cabbage","Eggplant"), size=884)),
  Amt = sample(seq(1, 40, by = 0.25), size = 884, replace = TRUE)
)
random <- sample(seq(1, 884, by = 1), size = 100, replace = TRUE) # to randomly introduce 100 NAs to Amt vector
mwe$Amt[random] <- NA
```

**Data frame**

```
    Site     Food   Amt
1 Office  Cabbage 16.50
2   Home    Apple 36.00
3 Office      Egg  7.25
4   Home    Onion 16.00
5 Office Eggplant 36.50
6   Home     Nuts    NA
```

**Summary Code**

```
dfsummary <- mwe %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Food, Site) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(Median = round(median(Amt, na.rm=TRUE), digits=2), N = n()) %>%
  ungroup()
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  Food   Site   Median     N
  <fct>  <fct>   <dbl> <int>
1 Apple  Home     17      34
2 Apple  Office   22.2    34
3 Banana Home     19.5    34
4 Banana Office   19.9    34
5 Bean   Home     20      34
6 Bean   Office   18      34
```

Some food items showed NA values, however they made their way in the `N` count. I simply do not want to count those with `NA`s in the `Amt` vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can `filter` at the top and then do the `summarise` without changing the code

```
library(dplyr)
mwe %>% 
   filter(!is.na(Amt)) %>% 
   dplyr::group_by(Food, Site) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(Median = round(median(Amt, na.rm=TRUE), digits=2),
       N = n()) %>%
    ungroup()
```

---

Or another option is to change the `n()` to `sum(!is.na(Amt))`

```
mwe %>%
    dplyr::group_by(Food, Site) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(Median = round(median(Amt, na.rm=TRUE), digits=2), 
         N = sum(!is.na(Amt))) %>%
    ungroup()
```

Comment: `sum(!is.na(.))` didn't work bcz I think `.` means the piped *data* but `sum(!is.na(Amt))` works.

Comment: @doctorate that was a typo, I did update that part